# Recursively create Tree from List

Tags: c#, generics, recursion, tree

I have a list of nested comments that essentially form a tree.

```
//Non-Relevant properties (Like Body, Creator etc) excluded
internal class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int ParentItemID { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }
}
```

First, I get a list of `Posts` from a database, then I get all `Comments where ItemID == Posts[all].id`

I want to loop through a flat List and create a nested, or tree List.

It goes like this:

If the `ParentItemID == 0`, then we have a top level comment. If `ParentItemID > 0` we need to match `ParentItemID` to a Comment `ID`, and add the child Comment to the Parent Comments List.

Where I'm stuck is, I've only used recursion in the past to navigate files and folders. This doesn't allow me to instantiate a collection and hold on to it through subsequent recursions.

It also seems silly to instantiate the list outside the recursion, and then loop through all items each time I want to add an item.

I'm sure there is a good solid pattern for doing this, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just loop through all comments and get the child comments for each:

```
foreach (Comment comment in comments) {
  comment.ChildComments =
    comments.Where(c => c.ParentItemID == comment.ItemID).ToList();
}
```

Another alternative that would perform better (if that is needed) would be to group the comments on the `ParentItemID` and create a `Dictionary<int, List<Comment>>` from that, then just loop through the comments like above and get the lists from the dictionary.

Comment: I believe that OP has a flat list and he wants to convert it to a nested model.

Comment: @AndreCalil: Yes, it does that.

Comment: That's true, and i'll keep the question open for a bit, but it's possible I need to avoid creating the flat list in the first place.

Comment: @Guffa But if I have a List<Comment> where count is 100 at the top level, this won't remove Child Comments from the top level, once they find their node down the tree, will it?

Comment: @Wesley: No. You would use `comments.Where(c => c.ParentItemID == 0).ToList()` to get the top level.

Comment: @Guffa Indeed, it does. Sorry.

Comment: @Guffa I like your photography.

Answer (score 3):

Guffa's solution is way prettier, but here is an alternative:

```
    public static List<Comment> ToTree(List<Comment> FlatCommentsList)
    {
        List<Comment> TopComments = FlatCommentsList.Where<Comment>(x => x.ParentItemID == 0).ToList();

        List<Comment> NestedComments = FlatCommentsList.Where<Comment>(x => x.ParentItemID > 0).ToList();

        List<int> IdsToRemove;

        while (NestedComments.Count > 0)
        {
            IdsToRemove = new List<int>();

            NestedComments.ForEach(x =>
            {
                Comment ParentComment = TopComments.Where<Comment>(y => y.ItemID == x.ParentItemID).SingleOrDefault<Comment>();

                if (ParentComment != null)
                {
                    ParentComment.ChildComments.Add(x);
                    IdsToRemove.Add(x.ItemID);
                }    
            });

            NestedComments.RemoveAll(x => IdsToRemove.Contains(x.ItemID));
        }

        return TopComments;
    }
```

It has no recursion as well, but it does its job. I'm a very fan of recursion, but I just don't think we need it here.

Answer (score 1):

Separating top-level and nested comments can be done with LINQ and `GroupBy`:

```
var grouped = comments.GroupBy(c => c.ParentItemId == 0);
var topLevel = grouped.Single(g => g.Key);
var nested = grouped.Single(g => !g.Key);
```

(the results of these operations will not actually be computed until you iterate over the sequences or use a method such as `ToList()` on them)

Attaching nested comments to their parents can be done like Guffa's approach (slow for lots of comments, does not use extra memory) or you can do a classic time-space tradeoff (fast for lots of comments, needs extra memory):

```
var dictionary = comments.ToDictionary(c => c.Id);
foreach (nested as comment) {
    dictionary[comment.ParentItemId].ChildComments.Add(comment);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I might have to do some tests on this one, and consider likely usage scenarios.